# Numpy where broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

`df['col1']=np.where(sum(df['col1'])==0, np.array([]), df['col1'])`
Col1 values are numpy arrays

Error: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Comment: What are you looking to do? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I want to replace a cell value in a dataframe under the column 'Col1' that is a zero array with an empty array. If it's not a zero array then retain the array as it is

Comment: col1
--------
[0,0,0..0]
[1,2,3,4..10]
[0.,0,0...0]

Should become
col1
-----
[ ]
[1,2,3,4..10]
[ ]

Comment: where's the rest of the error message?  Do you recognize the shapes?

Comment: If you consider the arguments to `where`, all three arrays `(condition, X, Y)` must be similar shape. in your example `X` is not the same shape as `condition` or `Y` which get their shape from `df['col1']`

Comment: Why are you using `np.array([])`?  That's a (0,) shape array, 1d with 0 elements.  When using `where` make sure each of the 3 arguments makes sense by itself. `where` does not "iterate".  To get more help you need to provide a small sample dataframe (or series).  And clearly demonstrate what you expect to do.  Don't be sloppy with terms like "zero array" and "empty array".  Those are not defined numpy terms.